# When could CPA work against non-deterministic encryption schemes?

Tags: encryption, chosen-plaintext-attack, deterministic-encryption

Is there a non-deterministic encryption scheme that is vulnerable to a CPA? I got asked this in an interview and I answered with no but the interviewer said that my answer is wrong. Would somebody clarify if this is possible?

Comment: The obvious way to think about this is to try to answer the question "can you devise a non-deterministic encryption scheme that is vulnerable to a CPA"?

Comment: A little history: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#BEAST_attack

Comment: @DanielS: actually, the problem with CBC mode encryption in TLS 1.0 was that it *wasn't* nondeterministic :-)  Instead, it was a deterministic function if you included the previous ciphertext.

Comment: @poncho I'd personally describe the issue as allowing the plaintext to be chosen after the non-deterministic information, but this is semantics.

Comment: What about $\mathsf{Enc}(k,m)=(m,r)$ for uniformly chosen $r$ (from some space). Definitely not deterministic. How secure do you think it is?